# How to tenderize/soften steamed octopus

Tags: seafood, tenderizing, octopus

I have got some steamed Spanish octopus in the freezer that I'm going to grill and serve as an appetizer. From testing with a pairing knife it seems quite chewy.

I've had success in the past with fresh octopus after boiling for 90 minutes or so. I've also tried grilling pre-cooked frozen octopus and it was chewy. Everything I've read at this point is about preparing fresh but I'm not sure how to apply this to the pre-steamed stuff I have.

I don't know if I should I cook it some more or if I should I tenderize it some how (is massaging it after steaming a thing?)

What can I do at this stage to serve tender octopus?

Thanks!

Comment: Beats me.  The steaming is supposed to keep it from getting chewy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried this myself, but everything I've read [from trustworthy sources] says the longer you cook it, the softer it gets, like braising steak etc. High collagen = long cook.

From that I'd extrapolate that if it's not tender enough after the pre-cook, then boiling it some more would help; before finally grilling it.

[Serious eats](https://www.seriouseats.com/how-to-cook-octopus) [though they are discussing fresh not pre-cooked] say that no amount of hammering makes any difference. They also suggest chilling between boiling & searing.

If you've time, I'd test a bit first, see how much extra boiling it needs.

Comment: I tried this and it worked. I boiled for an extra 45-60 minutes until knife tender before a quick grill and it came out tender and crispy. My only regret was boiling over steaming, the skin lost some integrity an parts of it fell off.